# Organize groups with timestamps in NoSQL

Tags: firebase

I have a question regarding the formatting of data in a nosql database

I have the following use case:

```
n User can be in 
n Groups where each user has
   1 time goal per day
   1 time he is currently tracking (which increments during the day)
```

The goal: Each user works toward a goal (in minutes) per day and can see each others progress.
The hardest part for me is the time goal. I have no idea how to structure that.

My thinking right now:

```
Users
    unique_id:
        name: user1
        timeTracked:{
              {11.02.2023:45}
        }groups:[group1, group2, group3]
groups
    groups1:
        members:{user1,user2...}
        time:{
              22.02.22:{
                    user1:43
                    user2:60
              }....
        goals:{
              22.02.22:{
                    user1:80
```

Would that be a sensible way of structuring the data? That would make it quite hard to track if users have achieved their goals in the past: If I only have a timestamp from 05.02.22 because the user didn't change their current goal, I would have to extrapolate it for the days up until 11.02.22

Comment: Can you perform queries that return the desired data?

Comment: Hey @AlexMamo not really if user a wants to know how much time the other users are contributing to their individual goals, I would have to  to fetch "time" and "goals" for each user and then divide time/goal to see which percentage each user has don of their goal

Comment: In the NoSQL world, we are usually structuring a database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those **exact** queries?

Comment: I didn't understand your remark about someone needing to comment so you could vote on answers - you should be able to do that anyway. Let me know at `@halfer` if you cannot accept/vote on an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make a separated collection for each user's time goals.
The separated collection will store the users' time goal for a specific day.

```
user_id: "user1"
date: "2020-02-15"
goal: 54
```

You will be able to track each user's progress towards their goal for each day easily, even if they don't update their current time tracking.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult with only this data. But I think that a structure that represents the objectives by group and user can help.

```
"Users": {
    "user1": {
        "id": "user1",
        "name": "Alice",
        "groups": [
            "group1",
            "group2"
        ]
    }
},

"Groups": {
    "group1": ["user1", "user2"],
    "group2": ["user1", "user3", "user5"]
},

"Goals": {
    "group1": {
        "user1": {
            "22-02-2023": {
                "goal": "30",
                "work": "22"
            },
            "23-02-2023": {
                "goal": "20",
                "work": "21"
            }
        },
        "user2": {
            "22-02-2023": {
                "goal": "30",
                "work": "22"
            },
            "23-02-2023": {
                "goal": "20",
                "work": "21"
            }
        }        
    },
    "group2": {
        "user1": {
            "22-02-2023": {
                "goal": "10",
                "work": "12"
            },
            "23-02-2023": {
                "goal": "15",
                "work": "20"
            }
        },
        "user3": {
            "22-02-2023": {
                "goal": "35",
                "work": "18"
            },
            "23-02-2023": {
                "goal": "10",
                "work": "10"
            }
        }        
    }
}
```